# Add an array value to another array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I add an array value to another array?

I get the array using:

```
NSMutableArray *pointsArray = [[result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
```

I want to add the first and the last value of `pointsArray` to another array.

Comment: do you want to append values in existent array?

Comment: Yes I want append old array values in new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as follows

```
NSUInteger totObjects = [pointsArray count];
[yourOtherArray addObject:[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0]]; //First Object
[yourOtherArray addObject:[pointsArray objectAtIndex:totObjects-1]]; //Last Object
```

Comment: is that the yourOtherArray  start index from the 0 to 2

Comment: if i add the  array into the other array than how can i get the new array 1st and last array value .Which has old array value

Comment: @Shima you mean to say yourOtherArray already has few objects in that ? and you want to get first and last value of that also ?

Comment: pointsArray = [[result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain]; NSInteger totobjects = [pointsArray count]; [annArray addObject:[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0]]; [annArray addObject:[pointsArray lastObject]]; NSLog(@"This fro thr %@",[annArray objectAtIndex:0]);

Comment: @Shima have you initialized annArray ?

Comment: Made it NSUInteger... shouldn't matter in reality, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
[array addObject:[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0]]; //First Object
[array addObject:[pointsArray lastObject]]; //Last Object
```

But this `array` should be an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of array using `objectAtIndex:` method of `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just add like this

```
NSArray *otherArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0], [pointsArray objectAtIndex:[pointsArray count]-1],nil];
```

Comment: pointsArray = [[result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
 NSInteger totobjects = [pointsArray count];
 [annArray addObject:[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
 [annArray addObject:[pointsArray lastObject]];
 NSLog(@"This fro thr %@",[annArray objectAtIndex:0]);

Comment: did you alloc init the annArray

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using this:

```
NSMutableArray *recentPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//add one object to the array
[recentPhotos addObject: selectPhotos];
```